# open time/datePicker on button click like google Calendar does

Tags: android, datepicker

so i want a time and a date picker to pop up when i click on a button look google Calendar does when you press the fab button on the bottom right. There will be a new window which shows up a date and a time and when you click one of them a picker opens.

Im not sure if i need to create a fragment with a time picker in it and just make the size smaller or if i have to create one via code.

**This is my code:**

public class NewEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private String[] arraySpinner;
private Button date_from;
private Button date_to;
private Button time_from;
private Button time_to;
private EditText title;
private EditText invite;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_event_fragment);
    findviewbyids();
    initPickers();

}

public void findviewbyids(){
    date_from    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_date_from);
    time_from    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_time_from);
    date_to  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_date_to);
    time_to  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_time_to);
    title  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_title);
    invite  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_invite);

}

public void initPickers(){
    Date today = new Date();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    DateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");


    String reportDate = df.format(today);
    String reportTime = tf.format(today);

    date_from.setText(reportDate);
    time_from.setText(reportTime);
    date_to.setText(reportDate);
    time_to.setText(reportTime);

    date_from.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    date_to.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    time_from.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    time_to.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    date_from.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    date_to.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    time_from.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    time_to.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Spinner group = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_group);

    this.arraySpinner = new String[] {
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
    group.setAdapter(adapter);


    date_from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });


}
```

}

now when i click on the **date_from** button a datePicker should appear and after setting the date it should overwrite the text on **date_from**

i hope you get what i mean

Update:

ok i solved it like this:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (id == 999) {
        df.format(today);
        month = today.getMonth();
        year = today.getYear();
        day = today.getDay();
        DatePickerDialog dlg = new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
        return dlg;
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        year = arg1;
        month = arg2;
        day = arg3;
        Date date = new Date(year,month,day);
        df.format(date);
        reportDate = df.format(date);
        date_from.setText(reportDate);
    }
};
```

now i got this problems:
somehow when the dialog pops up it tells me its the year 116 and that we have Friday the 3rd.

when i select a date then for example 6.10.2016 my Button shows up 3800/00/06

so that means it only gets the correct day.

but why?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm ?? This is standard way to use date picker, I have a feeling that that's what you need.

Comment: not exactly.. i want a real calendar not just a picker

Comment: Then I am not sure what are you trying to make, nor what do you mean by "real" calendar.

Comment: this is just a date picker i want a real calendar to pop up like te google calendar does